# end-to-end joint training of a deep neural network and a CNN

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, training-data

I would like to feed a set of bits into a neural network,  which will embed them into a color image that it will generate (let's call this neural network: the embeddingNN)

-We would then give this resulting color image to a CNN (lets call it the recognizer) in order to recover the original message (the set of bits).

- We would like to perform a joint end-to-end training to these NNs.

I assume that we would need to define a "joint" loss function. But how can we handle the fact that the output from of the embeddedNN needs to be input of the recognizerNN? this implies that we would run the first network in a different session that the second one, whereas we have one joint function, with references to both models?

How can we perform this on TF?

Comment: Do you labels/gold data for the embedingNN?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It sounds like you are trying to embed a secret message into the image and then retrieve it.  Also, I believe you have an **unspoken requirement** that the image cannot be completely destroyed and just simply replaced with the with the bits but that the image needs to remain such qualities that it still appears to a human what it was originally.

Comment: @wontonimo. yes, that is very close to the requirements. in the case we wouldnt care ab keeping the look, I thought about it a bit more since, & i think i'd need to define the 2 NNs s as 1 model in TF, then while running its session pass two it two parameters ( Y1, L), where Y is the output of the embeddingNN and L is the joint loss function. when given to TF in this order, it will first compute Y, which is needed to the subsequent computation of L. (I initially was thinking of the two neural networks as having to be implemented as two separate models in TF). Does it sound reasonable?

Comment: @wontonimo . as for the image needing to keep the same look even with the embedded message, i think i would add it as an extra term to the joint back propagation?

Comment: I've had a long discussion with a past coworker about something similar and he just decided to use the lowest order bits of the image, no NN.  I love tensorflow and making NNs, but maybe just straight manipulation is your easiest (and most efficient) method.

Comment: on further thought, if you wanted to use a NN to encode/decode the message, you could keep with my suggestion above about using the lowest order bit and then use NN to **just** encode/decode the message that floods the lowest order bit.  This would satisfy a requirement to use an image, to not distort the image too much, and use a NN to embed and retrieve a message.